# ActiveResource: how to handle namespaced routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, activeresource

I have two applications. One application with routes like:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :things
  end
end
```

And another that I hope to connect to it via ActiveResource.

What's the right way to connect to the first application's `api/v1/things` route with ActiveResource?

Right now it looks a whole lot like I will have to implement custom_method_collection_url but that feels like a hack - is it the only way?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit "`What's the right way to connect to this application's api/v1/things route with ActiveResource?`" You want to connect to this path from within the application?

Comment: Sorry I never responded. Connect to it with ARes from a different rails application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I implemented `custom_method_collection_url`. There was no better way that I could discern.